# Segmentation fault when creating a row-major array

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to implement a row-major array, which is basically a single dimension representation of a 2D array.

This is my class definition

```
class RMA{
    public:

    RMA(){
        size_=0;
        row_=0;
        column_=0;
        arr_ = new double[size_];
    }

    RMA(int n, int m){
        size_ = n*m;
        column_ = m;
        row_ = n;
        if(size_== 0) arr_ = 0;
            else arr_ = new double[size_];
    }

    RMA(const RMA& arr) {
        size_ = arr.size_;
        if(this != &arr){
            delete [] arr_;
            arr_ = new double[size_];
            for(int i=0; i<size_; i++){
                arr_[i] = arr.arr_[i];
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }

    const double& operator() (int n, int m) const{
        return arr_[n*column_+m];
    }

    double& operator()(int n, int m){
        return arr_[n*column_+m];
    }  
    ~RMA(){delete[] arr_ ;}

    private:
        int size_;
        int column_;
        int row_;
        double* arr_;
}
```

I've a calling function which creates the array.

```
RMA create_array() {
    RMA arr;
    arr = RMA(N, M);
    std::cout<<"success";
    return arr;
}
```

And this is my client

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    RMA arr = create_array();
    return 0;
}
```

I end up getting segmentation fault. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Where does the fault occur?  What were you attempting to do when it occurred?

Comment: `arr_ = new double[size_];` how big was that `size_` again ? And your code violates at least one part of the [**`Rule of Three`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) *multiple* times.

Comment: The fault occurs when I call create_array()

Comment: the size is about 2 million

Comment: You violated the [rule of three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: Added copy constructor

Answer (score 1):

You use operations, that instead of cloning array, take a shallow copy of an object, and when destructors are used, they try to release the same memory block.

Implement the following operations:

```
RMA::RMA(const RMA&); // copy constructor - clone buffer
RMA& operator=(const &RMA); // assignment - clone buffer, release old
```

Also instead of:

```
 RMA rma;
 rma = RMA(a,b);
```

Use:

```
 RMA rma = RMA(a,b) or RMA rma(a,b);
```

Edit: constructor code:

```
RMA::RMA(const RMA &rma) : size_(0), row_(0), column_(0), buffer_(0)
{
   *this = rma;
}

RMA &operator=(const RMA&rma)
{
   double *old = buffer_;
   size_ = rma.size_;
   row_ = rma.row_;
   column_ = rma.column_;
   buffer_ = new double[size_];
   memcpy(buffer_, rma.buffer_, sizeof(buffer_[0]) * size_);
   delete []old;
   return *this;
}
```

Comment: Added the copy constructor, but now I'm getting the error
returning a value from a constructor
       return *this;

Comment: @Antithesis constructor shall not return value.

Comment: Do i need to add double buffer_ to my private attributes.Not sure why you added this.

Comment: That copy-ctor is exactly the *opposite* of a [copy/swap idiom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom), which would be preferred. If you're going provide one defined via invoke of another regarding copy-ctor and assignment operator, this is exactly the opposite way it should be done.

Comment: You should throw in the move ctor & assignment operator too.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to get rid of all the `new`/`delete`, copy-constructors, and fluff. Use a private member variable to manage the memory, and follow the [Rule of Zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Like this:

```
struct RMA
{
    RMA(size_t r = 0, size_t c = 0)
        : row(r), column(c), arr(r * c) {}

    const double& operator() (int n, int m) const
        { return arr[n * column + m]; }

    double& operator() (int n, int m)
        { return arr[n * column + m]; }

private:
    std::vector<double> arr;
    size_t row, column;
};
```

That's it. You should not write any copy-constructor, assignment operator, move whatever, because the default-generated ones already do the right thing.

NB. `row` is actually redundant in my example too, you could remove it and calculate it when needed as `arr.size() / column`.

You could use `.at( )` instead of `[ ]` on vector in order to throw an exception for out-of-bounds access, instead of causing undefined behaviour.